# What does the as_json parameter for show_versions do in pandas?

Tags: python, json, pandas

When displaying version of Pandas library:

```
   print(pd.show_versions(as_json=True)
```

OUTPUT:

```
{'system': {'commit': None, 'python': '3.7.3.final.0', 'python-bits': 64, 'OS': 'Windows', 'OS-release': '10', 'machine': 'AMD64', 'processor': 'Intel64 Family 6 Model 78 Stepping 3, GenuineIntel', 'byteorder': 'little', 'LC_ALL': 'None', 'LANG': 'en', 'LOCALE': 'None.None'}, 'dependencies': {'pandas': '0.24.2', 'pytest': '4.3.1', 'pip': '19.0.3', 'setuptools': '40.8.0', 'Cython': '0.29.6', 'numpy': '1.16.2', 'scipy': '1.2.1', 'pyarrow': None, 'xarray': None, 'IPython': '7.4.0', 'sphinx': '1.8.5', 'patsy': '0.5.1', 'dateutil': '2.8.0', 'pytz': '2018.9', 'blosc': None, 'bottleneck': '1.2.1', 'tables': '3.5.1', 'numexpr': '2.6.9', 'feather': None, 'matplotlib': '3.0.3', 'openpyxl': '2.6.1', 'xlrd': '1.2.0', 'xlwt': '1.3.0', 'xlsxwriter': '1.1.5', 'lxml.etree': '4.3.2', 'bs4': '4.7.1', 'html5lib': '1.0.1', 'sqlalchemy': '1.3.1', 'pymysql': None, 'psycopg2': None, 'jinja2': '2.10', 's3fs': None, 'fastparquet': None, 'pandas_gbq': None, 'pandas_datareader': None, 'gcsfs': None}}
None
```

What is the significance of **as_json=True** here?

Comment: Considering that the function is almost entirely undocumented, this question seems reasonable. Trying a function out doesn't guarantee you'll discover all of its behavior. It doesn't look like this function even outputs JSON.

Comment: It produces a Python dict which is JSON serializable so it's kind of self explanatory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some context: `pd.show_versions()` is built-in function to aid users in creating [bug reports](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/development/contributing.html#bug-reports-and-enhancement-requests) for pandas.

The help page does not require users to pass in `as_json=True`, but [looking at the source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/658840d410f90cb143694ff62faf43aec8a52c51/pandas/util/_print_versions.py#L106), it looks like it's a formatting option.

Here's what both looks like:

```
>>> pd.show_versions()                                                       
INSTALLED VERSIONS
------------------
commit           : None
python           : 3.8.0.final.0
python-bits      : 64
... many lines omitted ...
xlrd             : 1.2.0
xlwt             : 1.3.0
xlsxwriter       : 1.2.2

>>> pd.show_versions(as_json=True)                                           
{'system': {'commit': None, ... , 'LOCALE': 'en_US.UTF-
8'}, 'dependencies': {'pandas': '0.25.2', ... , 'xlwt': '1.3.0'}}
```